# Reusing an Array With Functions

Tags: excel, vba, dijkstra

I have two different functions that require access to the same array (the array isn't a constant; it will be edited and appended to whenever the function is used within a cell in the sheet).

I want to make this array available to both of them. The array needs to be multi-dimensional (or be a UDT that can have multiple elements within it, like I tried in my code below), and it needs to be able to be dynamically resized. Here is some sample code (edited a bit) I have, but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
Option Base 1

Private Type PathsArray
    Nodes() As String
End Type

' Instantiate the global array
Dim Paths(1 To 1) As PathsArray

Function SETTWENTY()

    ' Increase size of the array, preserving the current elements already inside it
    ReDim Preserve Paths(1 To UBound(Paths) + 1)

    ' Make the inner array be 20 elements long
    ReDim Preserve Paths(UBound(Paths)).Nodes(1 to 20)

    ' Return something random
    GETPATH = UBound(Paths)

End Function

Function SETTHIRTY()

    ' Increase size of the array, preserving the current elements already inside it
    ReDim Preserve Paths(1 To UBound(Paths) + 1)

    ' Make the inner array be 30 elements long
    ReDim Preserve Paths(UBound(Paths)).Nodes(1 to 30)

    ' Return something random
    GETPATH = UBound(Paths)

End Function
```

Anyone know why this won't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you are trying to resize a "static" module-level array. Here is a good description (from Chip Pearson) of the difference between "static" and "dynamic" VBA arrays:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm

You have a secondary problem in that your functions will return the VBA value `Empty` instead of the number of paths. In VBA, you return a value from a function by assigning the value to the name of the function.

In the code below, I fixed those problems by:

1. making the module-level array "dynamic"
2. adding an "init" routine to get your initial element in there
3. returning the values you expect from your functions

You might not really need (2) if your original `(1 To 1)` declaration wasn't really what you wanted anyway.

Note the use of `Option Explicit` re: (3). If you'd had that there, your original code with the "GETPATH" assignments would fail to compile, even after fixing (1).

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Private Type PathsArray
    Nodes() As String
End Type

' Just declare the module-level array
Dim Paths() As PathsArray

Public Sub init()
    ReDim Paths(1 To 1) As PathsArray
End Sub

Function SETTWENTY()

    ' Increase size of the array, preserving the current elements already inside it
    ReDim Preserve Paths(1 To UBound(Paths) + 1)

    ' Make the inner array be 20 elements long
    ReDim Preserve Paths(UBound(Paths)).Nodes(1 To 20)

    ' Return something random
    SETTWENTY = UBound(Paths)

End Function

Function SETTHIRTY()

    ' Increase size of the array, preserving the current elements already inside it
    ReDim Preserve Paths(1 To UBound(Paths) + 1)

    ' Make the inner array be 30 elements long
    ReDim Preserve Paths(UBound(Paths)).Nodes(1 To 30)

    ' Return something random
    SETTHIRTY = UBound(Paths)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation! I managed to sort out the problems with your help!